# Dropping a table partition avoiding the error ORA-00054

Tags: oracle, plsql, locking, partitioning

I need your opinion in this situation. I’ll try to explain the scenario. I have a Windows service that stores data in an Oracle database periodically. The table where this data is being stored is partitioned by date (Interval-Date Range Partitioning). The database also has a dbms_scheduler job that, among other operations, truncates and drops older partitions.

This approach has been working for some time, but recently I had an [ORA-00054](http://ora-00054.ora-code.com) error. After some investigation, the error was reproduced with the following steps:

1. Open one sqlplus session, disable auto-commit, and insert data in the
   partitioned table, *without committing* the changes;
2. Open another sqlplus session and truncate/drop an old partition (DDL
   operations are automatically committed, if I’m not mistaken). We
   will then get the ORA-00054 error.

There are some constraints worthy to be mentioned:

- I don’t have DBA access to the database;
- This is a legacy application and a complete refactoring isn’t
  feasible;

So, in your opinion, is there any way of dropping these old partitions, without the risk of running into an ORA-00054 error and without the intervention of the DBA? I can just delete the data, but the number of empty partitions will grow everyday.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

This error means somebody (or something) is working with the data in *the partition you are trying to drop*.  That is, the lock is granted at the partition level.  If nobody was using the partition your job could drop it.

Now you say this is a legacy app and you don't want to, or can't, refactor it.  Fair enough.  But there is clearly something not right if you have a process which is zapping data that some other process is using.  I don't agree with @tbone's suggestion of just looping until the lock is released: you can't just get rid of data which somebody is using with establishing why they are still working with data that they apparently should not be using.

So, the first step is to find out what the locking session is doing.  Why are they still amending this data your background job wants to retire?   Here's a [script which will help you establish which session has the lock](http://www.shutdownabort.com/dbaqueries/Performance_Locks_DML.php#Show-locked-objects).

Except that you "don't have DBA access to the database".  Hmmm, that's a curly one.  Basically this is not a problem which can be resolved without DBA access.

It seems like you have several issues to deal with.  Unfortunately for you, they are political and architectural rather than technical, and there's not much we can do to help you further.

Comment: fair enough, I agree that knowing what sessions are locking (and why) is needed, but I have seen tables setup with date range partitioning for the purpose of "aging out" old data and keeping only x months/years of data.  This seems to be that setup, and I'm guessing this purge job is running first of month or so.  If, for example, a direct path insert was occurring at that time, the user wasn't "using" the old data, its just that Oracle will lock the table (all partitions I believe).  So waiting for those inserts to complete would make sense.  I guess I'm saying try it and log why fails

Comment: Hi! Well, there's a Windows Service that is writing to that table periodically, using a bulk insert. The dbms_scheduler job removes the the old partitions, since they are partitioned by date. So, even though the partition dropping operation (by the dbms_scheduler job) and the writing operation are manipulating different partitions (and the job *never* deletes the "today" partition) I get this error. @tbone is right about the purpose of this partitioning, although the job runs daily. I think I'll try tbone's approach. It seems fair to me, given this specific situation.

Comment: @Moe - I tried this on my 11gR2 database, with two sessions: one inserting into a partition the other dropping partitions.  I could drop any partition except *the partition the other session was inserting into*.  Perhaps things are different in older versions of the database.

Comment: Hi @APC. You're right. I've done that test too, which turned things a little uglier to me :) Anyway, after the discussions with you guys, I think I have enough to perform a more in-depth analysis.

Comment: @APC: Regular inserts will work that way, but direct path inserts lock every partition, even if the insert doesn't insert any rows.  @Moe/@tbone: You can  reduce the locking by either using regular inserts or by specifying the partition name in the insert.

Comment: @jonearles - thanks, I didn't know that about Direct Path inserts.  That certainly sounds like it might explain Moe's situation.

Answer (score 3):

How about wrapping the truncate or drop in pl/sql that tries the operation in a loop, waiting x seconds between tries, for a max num of tries.  Then use dbms_scheduler to call that procedure/function.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://oracle-error.blogspot.com/2008/10/ora-00054-resource-busy-and-acquire.html) can help. Seems to be the same issue as the one that you discribe.
(ignore the comic sans, if you can) :)